# minimumNumberOfCalls not working in resilience4j

Tags: spring-boot, yaml, circuit-breaker, resilience4j

Using springboot 2.4 and resilience4j 1.5,

i have configured my yaml file,

```
resilience4j:
  circuitbreaker:
    configs:
      default:
        registerHealthIndicator: true
        slidingWindowSize: 10
        minimumNumberOfCalls: 5
        permittedNumberOfCallsInHalfOpenState: 3
        automaticTransitionFromOpenToHalfOpenEnabled: true
        waitDurationInOpenState: 50s
        failureRateThreshold: 50
        eventConsumerBufferSize: 10
    instances:
      movieCatalog:
                  baseConfig: default
```

and in the movieCatalog instance,

```
@RequestMapping("/{userId}")
@CircuitBreaker(name = CATALOG_SERVICE, fallbackMethod="fallBackCatalog")
public List<CatalogItem> getCatalog(@PathVariable("userId") String userId) {
    UserRating ratings = restTemplate.getForObject("http://ratings-data-service/ratingsdata/users/"+userId, UserRating.class);
    return ratings.getUserRatings().stream()
            .map(rating -> {
                Movie movie = restTemplate.getForObject("http://movie-info-sevice/movies/" + rating.getMovieId(), Movie.class);
                return new CatalogItem(movie.getName(), movie.getDescription(), rating.getRating());
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private List<CatalogItem> fallBackCatalog(Exception e) {
    List<CatalogItem> fallBack = new ArrayList<>();
    fallBack.add(new CatalogItem("movie1", "movie desc", 3));
    return fallBack;
}
```

i see that when i get an exception in the above getCatalog method the i get the fallback result immediately on the first call. my understanding is for the first 5 calls i should see an exception and from the 6 th call since more than 50% of the calls are exceptions(100% errors) i should see the fallback result in the 6th call. i have several errors before configuring fall back method, is there a cache which records the previous calls, and i guess if at all there is cache it should be cleared when the spring boot app is restarted right ? please explain if im missing something. any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The fallback mechanism is like a try/catch. It's independent of your CircuitBreaker configuration.
If you only want to execute a fallback method when the CircuitBreaker is open, then narrow down the scope from `Exception` to `CallNotPermittedException`.

Answer (score 0):

Resilience4J will fail-fast by throwing a CallNotPermittedException until the state changes to closed or according to our configuration.

So with a fallback method, when the circuit breaker trips to Open state, it will no longer throw a CallNotPermittedException but instead will return the response INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.

I also agree with @Robert Winkler